# Compute Engine Autoscaler and the Monitoring Agent

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

When using Compute Engine Autoscaler, is it possible to autoscale based on a cloud metric obtained by the [Monitoring Agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/) (Stackdriver)?

For example, I want to use the number of requests per second [serviced by Apache](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/apache) as a metric.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using the Developers Console select `Monitoring metric` as the value for the `Autoscale based on` drop down list and fill out `Target monitoring metric` with your desired [Cloud Monitoring metric](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cloud-monitoring-metrics).

You can accomplish this by using [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/autoscaler/create) command as well.

Comment: I cannot find in documentation metric identifiers for metrics from the Monitoring Agent. Only for standard metric or custom metric.